# Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous io.reactivex.Observer<model.TwitterResponse>)'

Tags: java, android, twitter, observers, reactivex

This code was working before but after I update the code, it started showing

> Cannot resolve method 'subscribe(anonymous io.reactivex.Observer<model.TwitterResponse>)'

Below is the sample code

```
public void callTwitterApi(final DisposableObserver observer, String URL, String twitterModel) {
  RestClient.getInstance(mActivity).getService().callTwitter(URL,twitterModel)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Observer<TwitterResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { }
        @Override
        public void onNext(TwitterResponse o) {observer.onNext(o); }
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) { observer.onError(e); }
        @Override
        public void onComplete() { observer.onComplete();
        }
      });
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: add signature of `callTwitter` this method

Comment: Mixing rxjava2 and rxjava3?